# How to change default java icon in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, icons, jfilechooser

I want to change the inbuilt java icon from `JFileChooser`. `JFrame` class has a `setIconImage()` method for set icon.But I couldn't find anything like that for `JFileChooser`. Without changing that coffee cup anyone can easily recognize that my software is made with java. Can anyone can help me to avoid this?

Comment: Why do you want to hide that the application has made with java?

Comment: There is no special reason...But I like to do so bro...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IIRC the icon for the JFileChooser is taken from the jFrame that is passed in. By changing the icon for the JFrame, you should also get the reflected icon change in the JFileChooser.

the code:

```
JFileChooser choice = new JFileChooser()
choice.showOpenDialog(parent);
```

The icon that is used is the icon from the parent.

Answer (score 7):

This could help:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File("C:/")){
    @Override
    protected JDialog createDialog( Component parent ) throws HeadlessException {
        JDialog dialog = super.createDialog( parent );
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage( 16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR );
        dialog.setIconImage( image );
        return dialog;
    }
};
fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is better than the chosen answer, because it allows **any** custom icon, not just inheriting from the parent.

Answer (score 3):

See:

- [How to change JFileChooser's title bar icon](http://www.coderanch.com/t/335982/GUI/java/change-JFileChooser-title-bar-icon).

Comment: @Down-voter, Not sure I understand the downvote? Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

```
javax.swing.JFileChooser jfc = new javax.swing.JFileChooser(new java.io.File("C:/Users/Documents")) {
            @Override
            protected javax.swing.JDialog createDialog(java.awt.Component parent) throws java.awt.HeadlessException {
                javax.swing.JDialog dialog = super.createDialog(parent);

                dialog.setIconImage(new
                        javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:/Img.png").getImage());

                return dialog;

            }
        };
```